# Change Debug Font Colour - Serilog C# .NET Core 3.1 Jetbrains Rider Mac OSX

Tags: c#, macos, asp.net-core, serilog, rider

I have just followed a tutorial that uses `Serilog` in conjunction with a C# .Net Core 3.1 web application.

All is working fine at the moment, but I noticed the font colour of the debug message is black and is clashing with the background colour of the `run` pane in Rider (Mac).

[image: run pane]

Here is my `appsettings.json` if helps:

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/log.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G} {Message}{NewLine:1}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please could you attach a screenshot of a preview box for `Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Colors`? Most of the console related colors can be set there.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue, except it is worse frankly when there are parameters, Uri's, etc. in the log entry.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same issue, ended up being an issue with Rider's Theme.

Go to: `Preferenes > Editor > Color Schemes > Console Colors > ANSI Colors`

Then select "White" and change the color to anything you want. Maybe a very clear light gray.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSMOJ.png)